# Do i need a return statement after an infinite loop?

Tags: c

Is this good code (is it readable, will the compiler compile it):

```
int is_thing_five() {
  while (1) {
    if (thing_is_ready) {
      return thing == 5;
    }

    update_thing();
  }
}
```

or does it have to have a return statement after the infinite loop

```
int is_thing_five() {
  while (1) {
    if (thing_is_ready) {
      return thing == 5;
    }

    update_thing();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does your compiler tell you when you try to compile it?

Comment: Question is compiler dependent. I expect most will compile this (`gcc` would surely do it). And for the return statement, again its up the compiler that you decided to use. `gcc` would compile without return statement and you'd be able to run.

Comment: Well... is there really an **after** the loop when talking about an infinite loop? It won't reach it so it's obsolete, right?

Comment: If the function never returns, why bother with a return value?  Just make it `void is_thing_five()`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle The function does return if the condition is met. There is no infinite loop involved here.

Comment: @Gerhardh The title specifically calls it an "infinite loop".  I probably should have been clear that I was pointing out the contradiction between the title and the posted code...

Comment: @AndrewHenle I assume the author calls any loop with a condition that is always true an "infinite" loop. Therefore I doubt the point will be understood in that way. And the author doesn't claim it never returns.

Comment: You could change the function to break out of the infinite loop when the thing is ready and return the value at the end of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, the behaviour of *using* a return value from a non-void function that does not have an explicit return value is *undefined*.

So, no you don't need the `return` statement, and you wouldn't need it even if the end of the function was reachable, so long as a caller of the function doesn't use the return value.

`int main` is an exception to this rule: you are allowed to call `main` from itself (indirectly or otherwise), and you are allowed to assume an implicit `return 0;` on any branch that doesn't have an explicit return value.

---

Interesting, before C11 the behaviour of a function with an infinite loop that "did nothing" was *undefined*. But C11 defines the behaviour by way of a footnote in the standard:

C11, 6.8.5 ad 6:

> An iteration statement whose controlling expression is not a constant expression,<sup>156)</sup> that performs no input/output operations, does not access volatile objects, and performs no synchronization or atomic operations in its body, controlling expression, or (in the case of a for statement) its expression-3, may be assumed by the implementation to terminate.<sup>157)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>157)</sup><sub>This is intended to allow compiler transformations such as removal of empty loops even when termination cannot be proven.</sub>

Comment: *So, no you don't need the `return` statement, and you wouldn't need it even if the end of the function was reachable, so long as a caller of the function doesn't use the return value.*  Except that in a few years someone will add a `break` to the loop so flow does reach the bottom of the function, and then someone will actually use the return value.  Given the code with `return 0;` at the bottom has already been written, there's no point in leaving it out, and there's potential substantial future consequences if it is left out. "This will never happen" is a bad start if you want reliability.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: In that case, I think a runtime assertion is superior to a return. At least then you might get a new compiler warning issued during a build, and failing that, a runtime failure if the assertion is reached.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't needed it. Some compilers however will give you a warning which you would suppress with a pragma, or suppress by having an extra return. And then that might also get you a warning on a different compiler, because the statement is unreachable.

For that piece of code, I'd try to move the if test into the while, so you have

```
int is_thing_five() 
{
    while (not thing_is_ready)
    {
         update_thing();
    }
    return thing == 5;
}
```

which is somewhat clearer as it doesn't have an infinite loop with a test to break out of it in the middle.